# ODE of LTI system

Tags: signal-processing, linear

Given an LTI system and for an input \$x(t) = a\cdot tu(t)\$ while \$u(t)\$ is Heaviside function you know that the output is \$y(t) = (t^4+t^3)u(t)\$.

If not given that the system has ODE, how can I mathematically prove that it has one?
In the frequency domain I can represent the transfer function as:
\$H(w) = \frac{24+6(jw)}{(jw)^3}\$. Can I just assume that \$P(D) = 24+6(jw)\$ and \$Q(D) = (jw)^3\$?